# Is including null fields in an API response considered a breaking change?

Tags: rest, response, httpresponse

I have changed the behaviour of an API (that previously did not include null fields) to include null fields. I was told that this was a breaking change but could not find reliable documentation on this subject.

Is this considered a breaking change ?

For example, the API that would previously return a response like this :

```
{
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

now returns reponses that also include null fields :

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a breaking change to include the null fields. The breaking change is that now there are "some" new fields. This might be unexpected for the frontend developers, because they didn't know wich fields there would be.

As a good practice, send always all the fields. If there are fields with null value, so be it, it's no problem. But if the frontend has an interface or mapping, fields that appear or disappear, that might be a problem.